# Called by third party through "share list". How to prevent create several Activity instance?

Tags: android, android-intent

My App has two Activities:
1.LoadingActivity: It's for receiving the data from other Apps.
2.MainPageActivity: When LoadingActivity finishing data processing, going to
MainPageActivity and showing the result.

My purpose is let my App keep on the foreground and the only one activity instance whenever called by other Apps.
If my App is in the background, when **User choose myApp in the share list**, my App would be foreground and show the result.
If my App not opened, when User choose myApp in the share list, my App would be opened and show the result on the foreground.
In order to satisfied the requirement, I do the code like followings.

I got problems:
**My App is running in the background.**
If get the sharing data from **"text copy"**, ***isTaskRoot()*** always return true.(Called by several times, there would be several activity instances)
But, if get the sharing data from **"Google Map share location"**, ***isTaskRoot()*** return false, not create another activity instance.
What's the difference between these two "share" situation?

My code:
1.Androidmanifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.test.activities.LoadingActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

2.LoadingActivity.java

```
public class LoadingScreenActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ... 
    if (!isTaskRoot()) {
    check3rdRequest(false, null);
    finish();
    return;     
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing loader inside separate activity is somewhat hardcore. please consider using fragment / fragment dialog / ProgressView on top of everything instead.

Then, to answer your question consider adding

```
android:launchMode= "singleInstance"
```

To the manifest